# Excel cells text over inserted image

Tags: vba, excel

How to make excel cell text to be over the image inserted on page?

Also this image must be controled from VBA. If i put this image in header or footer i cant control it as shape object from VBA with this code

```
Dim Sh As Shape
Dim I As Integer
I = 1
For Each Sh In Application.Caller.Worksheet.Shapes
    If Left(Sh.Name, 4) = f Then Sh.Visible = True Else Sh.Visible = False
Next
```

Comment: I don't think you can make an image go behind the text that is written in cells. You can, if you want, have text in a textbox that is on top of your image.

Comment: You can set a background for the entire sheet, just not for an individual cell. Go to Layout=>Background and select your background file.

Comment: But i need control from vba as i need show and hide it